# How to calculate dates to pass as arguments to pdfgantt?

Tags: pgfgantt, datetime2

I'm trying to work with dates in Latex (via Overleaf) with the `datetime2` and `pdfgantt` packages.

I have created a command to increment a date using `\DTMsavejulianday`. The below code shows that it is correctly computing the date, but it is not happy when passing the computed date into the `pdfgantt` package.

In overleaf when I try to use the result of the `\startDatePlusDays` command it complains `missing number, being treated as zero`.

Put simply, `\DTMsavedate` creates dates I can use, but `\DTMsavejulianday` does not. Where am I going wrong?

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

\DTMsavedate{StartDate}{2023-10-02}
\DTMsavedate{EndDate}{2023-10-22}

% a command to add some days to a date
\newcount\daycount
\newcommand{\startDatePlusDays}[1]{%
\DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{StartDate}{#1}\daycount%
\DTMsavejulianday{newDate}{\number\daycount}%
\DTMusedate{newDate}%
}

\newcommand\startDate{\DTMusedate{StartDate}}
\newcommand\theEndDate{\DTMusedate{EndDate}}
\newcommand\anotherEndDate{\startDatePlusDays{20}}

%these look OK when printed
theEndDate is \theEndDate\\
anotherEndDate is \anotherEndDate\\

%So why is anotherEndDate being treated as zero?
\begin{ganttchart}[hgrid, vgrid, inline, time slot format=isodate]{\startDate}{\theEndDate}
\gantttitlecalendar{month=name, day} 
\ganttnewline
\ganttbar{This works}{\startDate}{\theEndDate}\\
\ganttbar{This does not}{\startDate}{\anotherEndDate}\\
\end{ganttchart}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your diagnosis is not quite correct: there is nothing wrong with `\DTMsavejulianday`. The fundamental issue has to do with the expansion of several of the `\DTM...` macros.

For example, if you had rewritten your preamble as follows:

```
\newcount\daycount
\newcommand{\startDatePlusDays}[1]{%
\DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{StartDate}{#1}\daycount%
\DTMsavejulianday{newDate}{\number\daycount}%
%\DTMusedate{newDate}%   <= NOTE: \startDatePlusDays now just saves to newDate
}

\newcommand\startDate{\DTMusedate{StartDate}}
\newcommand\theEndDate{\DTMusedate{EndDate}}
\startDatePlusDays{15}  % <= sets newDate
\newcommand\anotherEndDate{\DTMusedate{newDate}}  % <= uses newDate
```

then the code compiles perfectfly fine. But if you had defined `\theEndDate` as

```
\newcommand\theEndDate{\DTMsavedate{EndDate}{2023-10-22}\DTMusedate{EndDate}}
```

You would get exactly the same error you got before.

The following makes for a workable interface:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\DTMsavedate{StartDate}{2023-10-02}
\DTMsavedate{EndDate}{2023-10-22}


% a command to add some days to a date and save it
\newcount\daycount
\newcommand{\saveStartDatePlusDays}[2]{%
\DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{StartDate}{#1}\daycount%
\DTMsavejulianday{#2}{\number\daycount}%
}

\newcommand\startDate{\DTMusedate{StartDate}}
\newcommand\theEndDate{\DTMusedate{EndDate}}

\newcommand\gantoffset[2]{%
    \saveStartDatePlusDays{#2}{tempdate}%
    \ganttbar{#1}{\startDate}{\DTMusedate{tempdate}}%
}

\begin{ganttchart}[hgrid, vgrid, inline, time slot format=isodate]{\startDate}{\theEndDate}
\gantttitlecalendar{month=name, day} 
\ganttnewline
\ganttbar{This works}{\startDate}{\theEndDate}\\
\gantoffset{This also works}{15}\\
\gantoffset{This does too!}{13}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]